# Bluetooth Auto connection

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am currently working on AOSP. I wanted to know how to stop the auto connection procedure which is in progress while a user requests for an inquiry of available devices. And I also want to re-start the auto connection once the inquiry is completed or user has aborted the enquiry.

I have to make these changes in the Android Source Code and I am currently working on Android P.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood your question well but reconnection or auto connection of bluetooth profiles is always handled by the state machine and there is no way to stop or pause it.

The only way to achieve this type of behaviour is to access the particular profile service via proxy and then on that service call this method:

profileService.setPriority(bluetoothDevice, BluetoothProfile.PRIORITY_OFF);

The above statement will make state machine not to process any connection requests on the specific profile on which you called this method and on the bluetoothDevice which you passed as parameter and once you are done with the query just call the same method again like this:

profileService.setPriority(device, BluetoothProfile.PRIORITY_ON);